# how to store the date quaterly of the months in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `invoices` (`invoice_no`, `supplier_id`, `customer_id`, `payment_id`, `issue_date`, `due_date`, `total`, `gst_type`, `gst`, `grandtotal`, `amt_owed`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (XCZ-INV, 1, , 1, , , , , , , , 2017-11-29 18:44:19, 2017-11-29 18:44:19))

Answer (score 0):

You don't sending any costumer_id to your database. But in your database, you say costumer_id can not be null.. You need to change that as "NULL"

Use this, it should works;

```
UPDATE invoices SET costumer_id = NULL
```